# Directory watching using Wathservice api

Tags: java, watchservice

I am writing a utility that watches a particular directory for new folders or files,once new folder or file is added i need to copy it to other location,i am using java watchservice,so the problem is if a directory is being written to the watching directory then how to ensure that the directory is completely written on not (for files i have used RandomAccessFiles to ensure this) so is there anything similar to check for directories